# urls and threads in disqus

Tags: disqus

I've read that disqus treats urls and threads as follows:

```
DISQUS will see http://example.com/#!/about and http://example.com/#!/blog as two different threads.
DISQUS will see http://example.com/#/about and http://example.com/#/blog as one thread with URL http://example.com/.
```

So if this is true, what will happen with the next urls?

```
http://example.com/#!/about/one and http://example.com/#!/about/two
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is imho not programming related.

Comment: Well, it's programming related because I'm trying to set the disqus javascript code in my html page.

Comment: I'd already tried too but I really don't know what it's the behaviour. Apparently these url are the same thread but I wanted to be 100% sure.